# @postmapping json payload as map<String, ?> with spring boot, empty map

Tags: json, spring-boot

I'm new to springboot and want to know

1. if it is really recommended to create a class for each request, even if the request body has different parameters, each with a different nature as my following example
2. what is wrong with my current case where `requestParams` is an empty map when post reaches inside the method

### Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/getFromDeviceDateRange", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<DailyUnitsDoubleBO>> getFromDeviceDateRange(@RequestParam Map<String, ?> requestParams) {
    Instant startDt;
    Instant endDt;
    Long deviceId;
    try {
        String startDtS = requestParams.get("startDt").toString();
        String endDtS = requestParams.get("endDt").toString();
        String deviceIdS = requestParams.get("deviceId").toString();
    ....
```

### Payload of post request

```
{"deviceId":17,"startDt":"2021-05-01","endDt":"2021-05-01","csvColumnAbbreviation":"PVV"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam` stands for **request parameter**, when `@RequestBody` is **for the body** of the request

So replace

`@RequestParam Map<String, ?> requestParams`

with

`@RequestBody Map<String, ?> requestParams`